# WPF - Program fails when using ToggleButton Trigger on IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf, crash, togglebutton, eventtrigger

I am getting a weird crash whenever I am trying to change a path fill using a trigger on a ToggleButton. After doing some process of elimination it seems that the actual trigger property is causing the program to crash.

When it crashes I am getting this:

> Problem signature: 
>  
>     Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3 
>     Problem Signature 01: briantestwpf.exe 
>     Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0 
>     Problem Signature 03: 54de1f87 
>     Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework 
>     Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18408 
>     Problem Signature 06: 52312f13 
>     Problem Signature 07: 65f2 
>     Problem Signature 08: 5e 
>     Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4 
>     Locale ID:    1033 
>     Additional Information 1: 0a9e 
>     Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 
>     Additional Information 3: 0a9e 
>     Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Here is the code in question, nothing fancy since I'm trying to mess with the concept. My Project Lead is also confused on this.

```
<ToggleButton Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="384" Height="41" Width="81">
            <Canvas>

                <Path x:Name="Arrow"
        Width="32"
        Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L0,2  "
        Fill="#FF827F96" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-15" Stretch="Fill" Height="29" />
            </Canvas>
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Path.Fill" Value="GhostWhite"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this --

```
<ToggleButton Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Top="384" Height="41" Width="81">
        <Canvas>
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Width="32" Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L0,2  " Fill="#FF827F96" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-15" Stretch="Fill" Height="29" >
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Path">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="GhostWhite"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Seems to not do anything when I add this. Runs fine but no change occurs

Comment: let me check, give me some time

Comment: my bad ... change Path.Fill to Stroke ....

    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="GhostWhite"/>


and its ghost white so you need to see that carefully...